# Discover and connect to unknown shares on an SMB server

Tags: samba

I have a server running SMB on the ports 139 & 445. I know its IP address.

Which steps should I follow to connect to the SMB daemon? I don't know which services are running.

Comment: You do know is running SMB of some sort. So what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
smbclient -L //1.2.3.4
smbclient //1.2.3.4/sharename -U username
```

Answer (score 0):

Smbd is a daemon which should be running in your machine for connecting purpose. if not, please start it by using following command.

```
service smbd start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/smbd start
```